# ¿Como puedo obtener una barra de rutas en eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

¿Como puedo obtener la barra que se ve en la imagen en eclipse?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4357/3834

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se llaman `breadcrumbs` y la barra aparece dando click derecho al código y despues `show in breadcrumbs`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]